# Flutter + Provider + Sqflite: Aggregated data state management

Tags: flutter, provider, sqflite

### Background

Say I have 30 sqlite db entities with their corresponding individual dart class models. Of those, many are aggregated and shown in several widgets of the app. CRUD operations should re-run the corresponding aggregation and update the respective ui/widgets that consume the data.

### Current state

Today I read from the db every time I build the widgets.

### Need

How can I have generic provider/listener for the aggregations as well as the entities without creating one provider for each entity and aggregated view? It should be able to resolve which widgets to update.

I want to have a state management layer, with a dependency tree, as opposed to reading from the db every time the widget is built.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that you want to have state management with the provider package, but you don't want to create types that extend `ChangeNotifier` to manage your data models.

You gonna have to extend `ChnageNotifier` in order to call `notifyListeners` where needed to update your UI. So at least create one type that extends `ChangeNotifier`, and have it manage all of your data objects. Generally, this is not a good as there is no reason not to create a type per each model.